Find all pairs of primes $p,q$ such that $16p^2+13q^2+5p^2q^2$ is a perfect square.
Find all pairs of primes $p,q$ such that $16p^2+13q^2+5p^2q^2$ is a perfect square.
Hello, I am Alek and I have this as a part of my homework. I know the problem must be easy-solvable, because it's first level in my textbook. I have tried different things like modules or maybe even simplifying it, but nothing has really made any progress and I can't even find easy solutions. I am preparing for a math competition. I am 8th grade, live in Europe and I know Fermat's theory, modules, some Lemma's and other theories. So if you could solve it using this knowledge it would be really helpful.
So I saw some suggestions in the comments.
Using mod 4 we can see either $p = 2$ or $q = 2$.
I checked $p = 2$:
$(a-8)(a+8) = 33q^2$.
This is easily solvable so I found solutions $p,q = (2,2), (2,3), (2,7)$
But now I am stumped at q = 2, because I get $36p^2 = a^2 - 52$ and so do I use just $\sqrt{52}$ ?
I just saw such an easy solution for $q=2$ Since $p,q$ are positive integers I can just make it out like this:
$(a-6p)(a+6p) = 52$ , which I can easily solve getting the solution $p,q = (2,2)$ , which we've already seen.
Thanks to everyone who helped me solve this!

Have you tried anything?

@XKH Yes I have, but nothing seems to work sadly. I have tried modules, simplifying it and other methods, but with no success.

I don't see myself how to answer at the moment, but it could depend on what tools you have at your disposal or which section of the textbook it falls under. For example, if you know about Legendre symbols and quadratic reciprocity and the exercise were to follow that up, then it might be a good place to start ($13$ having to be a square modulo $p$ here could give information on $p$), but that changes if all you have is more basic arithmetic and modulos.

@BrunoB I am actually 8th grade and this is for my advanced math. We're preparing for a big competition and I want to know how to solve this. I know Fermat's theory, modules  and some Lemma's, but nothing too serious for 8th grade math in Europe.

That's key information that should be included in the post itself.

@Sil Yeah I see it now. I'm just new to this so I don't really understand fully how to write questions.

Taking the expression $\mod 4$ reveals that one of $p$ or $q$ is $2$, but I don't see the next step from here.

Compare with this post.

Try : what happen if $p,q$ both are even & both are odd, p is even, q odd and p odd & q even

use, this : odd + odd = even, even +even= even, odd + even =odd

You are familiar with modular Arithmetic ?

@Guruprasad Yes i just used Bruno B's idea for where either p = 2 or q = 2. I checked one of the possible outcomes and found 3 solutions.

@Guruprasad Yes I am

Then try mod 2, mod 4

These are the only solutions to your problem ?

@Guruprasad I am pretty sure that this answer I posted is right. You can check it if you want.

I think you can look at it by modulo $4$. Trivially, $16p^2 + 13q^2 + 5p^2q^2 \equiv q^2 + p^2q^2 \mod 4$. All squares are $1$ or $0$ modulo $4$, so if $16p^2 + 13q^2 + 5p^2q^2$ is a perfect square, then $q^2 + p^2q^2$ is $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$. Let's consider this two possibilities.
I) $q^2 + p^2q^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$. It is possible only if q is even, so $q=2$, and we should find when $36p^2+52 = 2^2(9p^2 + 13)$ is a perfect square. But it happens only if $9p^2 + 13$ is a perfect square. If $p$ is odd, then $9p^2 + 13 \equiv 2 \mod 4$, so it can't be square, thus $p=2$. So, we have one solution $(2,2)$ in this case
II) $q^2 + p^2q^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$. This means $p=2$, so me should find when $33q^2 + 64 = a^2$ for some integer $a$. But then $33q^2 = (a - 8)(a+8)$. If $q$ divides both $a+8$ and $a-8$, then $q$ divides $(a+8) - (a-8) = 16$, i.e $q=2$. So $q^2$ divides either $a+8$ or $a-8$, thus $q^2 \le a + 8$. But then $33(a+8) \ge (a - 8)(a+8)$, so $a \le 41$. Thus $q^2 \le 49$ and $q\le 7$, so we should check three possibilities for $q$: $3$, $5$, $7$. This gives us another two solutions for $(p,q)$: $(2, 3)$, $(2, 7)$.

Check $mod 4$:
Either $p = 2$ or $q = 2$;
Checking $p = 2$ results in:
$a^2-64 = 33q^2$ or $(a-8)(a+8) = 33q^2$
From this we get solutions $(p,q) = (2,2), (2,3), (2,7)$
Then we check $q = 2$:
$36p^2 + 52 = a^2$  or  $(a-6p)(a+6p) = 52$
Here we get one solution and that is $(p,q) = (2,2)$, but we've already found that so there are only 3 solutions to this problem and they are:
$(p,q) = (2,2), (2,3), (2,7)$

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Imo your answer is fine as it is. (+1)

As the comments suggest, taking the expression modulo 4 results in $$q^2+p^2q^2\equiv0,1$$
from which we have a cases possible (note that if either $p,q$ are even they are 2):

If $q=2$ is even then we have no restrictions on $p$.
If $p=2$ is even then  again we have no restrictions on $q$.
If $q$ is odd, then $p$ must be even.
If $p$ is odd, then $q$ must be even.

These also imply that at least one of $p$ or $q$ is even so we only actually need to consider a couple of cases.
Case 1: $q=2$
Then we have $16p^2+52+20p^2=k^2$ for some integer $k$. Then we find $52=(k-6p)(k+6p)$ which only has one solution for $p$, namely $p=2$. So $(p,q)=(2,2)$ is the first solution.
Case 2: $q\neq2$
It follows from one of the conditions that $p=2$. Then we have $64+33q^2=k^2$ for some integer $k$. From here I found a bunch more solutions, namely $(p,q)=(2,2),(2,3),(2,7)$ and I've tested everything above that up until the primes less than 100 but I don't find anything else.
Claim: There are no solutions for $q> 7$ and $p=2$.
We have $33q^2=(k-8)(k+8)$ so either $q$ divides $k-8$ or $k+8$. Note that it can't divide both since then $q$ also divides $k+8-(k-8)=16$ but this implies $q=2$ which was assumed was not the case. So then $q^2\leq k+8$ so $33(k+8)\geq 33q^2=(k+8)(k-8)$ so we have $33\geq k-8$ and $k \leq 41$. Lastly, $33q^2\leq (41-8)(41+8)$ so $q^2\leq 49$ and $q \leq 7$ as desired.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
